# obtener fecha principal y fecha final en un DatePicker Vue

Tags: vue.js

estoy usando actualmente este componente en **vue.js** (un datePicker)

[Ejemplo](https://krystalcampioni.github.io/vue-hotel-datepicker/)

Todo funciona bien de acuerdo a las configuraciones que yo quiero.

```js
ptBr: {
  night: 'Día',
  nights: 'Días',
  'day-names': ['Dom', 'Lunes', 'Martes', 'Mier', 'Jueves', 'Viernes', 'Sab'],
  'check-in': 'Inicio',
  'check-out': 'Final',
  'month-names': ['Enero', 'Febrero', 'Marzo', 'Abril', 'Mayo', 'Junio', 'Julio', 'Agosto', 'Septiembre', 'Octubre', 'Noviembre', 'Diciembre']
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<HotelDatePicker :maxNights="15" :minNights="3" :i18n="ptBr">
</HotelDatePicker>
```

Así es como lo tengo, pero quiero obtener la fecha  principal que seleccione y la fecha final.
No sé cómo pasarlo a mis respectivas variables.

¿Cómo se hace? He leído la documentación pero no entiendo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La verdad que la documentación está bastante incompleta y no dice nada, pero rebuscando por el componente llegué a esta solución:

HTML:

```html
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <h1>Demo Hotel</h1>
    <HotelDatePicker
      @check-in-changed="checkIn"
      @check-out-changed="checkOut"
    />
    <p>CheckIn:</p>
    <pre>{{ dates.in }}</pre>

    <p>CheckOut:</p>
    <pre>{{ dates.out }}</pre>
  </div>
</template>
```

JS:

```
methods: {
  checkIn (val) {
    console.log(val)
    this.dates.in = val
  },
  checkOut (val) {
    console.log(val)
    this.dates.out = val
  }
}
```

Demo completa en **CodeSandbox**:
https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-template-qyizy?fontsize=14

Answer (score 1):

Tienes un par de eventos que debes tratar para obtener las fechas de entrada y salida: `checkInChanged` y `checkOutChanged`

Sin haber usado nunca el componente, podría ser algo como esto:

```
<HotelDatePicker
    :maxNights="15"
    :minNights="3"
    :i18n="ptBr"
    v-on:checkInChanged="fechaEntrada = $checkIn"
    v-on:checkOutChanged="fechaSalida = $checkOut">
</HotelDatePicker>
```